# xml reader and namespaces in c#

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmlreader

i am trying to read xml data using xml reader , the xml file include alot of prefixes so i included the namespaces in an `XmlNamespaceManager` , example code

```
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileName))
{
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
    nsmanager.AddNamespace("s", "http://www.google.com/shopping/api/schemas/2010");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "s:name":
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                break;
            case "s:condition": 
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

its outputing empty lines, is this the right way to include the namespaces?

in vb.net i imported the namespaces as

```
Imports <xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
Imports <xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
Imports <xmlns:rh="ReportHub">
Imports <xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
Imports <xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
Imports <xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">
Imports <xmlns:s="http://www.google.com/shopping/api/schemas/2010">
```

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the input XML file?

Comment: @JeremyThompson just did, the complete xml file contains multiple snippets like the above, complete xml files a couple of the above xml and namespaces i included in the vb.net code snippet.

Comment: Do you particularly have to use `XmlReader`? I usually find that LINQ to XML makes working with namespaces *much* simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet i am not really sure but speed is important since i will be parsing multiple files per second and xmlreader is supposed to be faster, things were really simple in vb.net!

Comment: @user1590636: Until you've benchmarked anything and *proved* that the difference between LINQ to XML and `XmlReader` is significant, I wouldn't *assume* that you have to use `XmlReader`.

Comment: @user1590636 If speed is important **and** you're using XML...good luck =/

Comment: @Yuck its not my XML , its XML from different online sources.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by using `reader.ReadElementString` rather than `reader.Value`